# NServiceBus and MSDTC across domains?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, nservicebus, msdtc

So I'm trying to use NServiceBus and everything goes fine until my application tries to write data to the database via EF6, where I consistently get this exception:

> 2016-11-18 13:35:28.340 INFO  NServiceBus.RecoverabilityExecutor
>   Immediate Retry is going to retry message
>   '28392aef-de00-4162-8cca-a6c200c0e68e' because of an exception:
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider
>   failed on Open. --->
>   System.Transactions.TransactionManagerCommunicationException:
>   Communication with the underlying transaction manager has failed. --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The MSDTC transaction
>   manager was unable to pull the transaction from the source transaction
>   manager due to communication problems. Possible causes are: a firewall
>   is present and it doesn't have an exception for the MSDTC process, the
>   two machines cannot find each other by their NetBIOS names, or the
>   support for network transactions is not enabled for one of the two
>   transaction managers. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D02B)    at
>   System.Transactions.Oletx.IDtcProxyShimFactory.ReceiveTransaction(UInt32
>   propgationTokenSize, Byte[] propgationToken, IntPtr managedIdentifier,
>   Guid& transactionIdentifier, OletxTransactionIsolationLevel&
>   isolationLevel, ITransactionShim& transactionShim)    at
>   System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetOletxTransactionFromTransmitterPropigationToken(Byte[]
>   propagationToken)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetOletxTransactionFromTransmitterPropigationToken(Byte[]
>   propagationToken)    at
>   System.Transactions.TransactionStatePSPEOperation.PSPEPromote(InternalTransaction
>   tx)    at
>   System.Transactions.TransactionStateDelegatedBase.EnterState(InternalTransaction
>   tx)    at
>   System.Transactions.EnlistableStates.Promote(InternalTransaction tx)
>   at System.Transactions.Transaction.Promote()    at
>   System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.ConvertToOletxTransaction(Transaction
>   transaction)    at
>   System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetExportCookie(Transaction
>   transaction, Byte[] whereabouts)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.GetTransactionCookie(Transaction
>   transaction, Byte[] whereAbouts)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistNonNull(Transaction
>   tx)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.Enlist(Transaction tx)
>   at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.ActivateConnection(Transaction
>   transaction)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.PrepareConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionInternal obj, Transaction transaction)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass4.<b__3>d__6.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.d__9`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.<OpenAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.<OpenAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<EnsureConnectionAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<ExecuteInTransactionAsync>d__3d`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.d__9`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<GetResultsAsync>d__e.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyAsyncEnumerator`1.<FirstMoveNextAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.<ForEachAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at
>   DAS.Services.Notifications.Data.Repository.AccountConfigurationRepository.<GetConfigurationAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\source\DigitalAirStrike\DAS_Platform\das.services.notifications\src\DAS.Services.Notifications.Data\Repository\AccountConfigurationRepository.cs:line
>   38
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   DAS.Services.Notifications.Service.Sms.SmsService.d__8.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\source\DigitalAirStrike\DAS_Platform\das.services.notifications\src\DAS.Services.Notifications.Service\Sms\SmsService.cs:line
>   92
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   DAS.Services.Notifications.Service.Sms.SmsService.<SendTextMessageAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\source\DigitalAirStrike\DAS_Platform\das.services.notifications\src\DAS.Services.Notifications.Service\Sms\SmsService.cs:line
>   76
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>
>   at
>   DAS.Services.Notifications.Command.MessageDelivery.SmsDeliveryStrategy.<Deliver>d__3.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\source\DigitalAirStrike\DAS_Platform\das.services.notifications\src\DAS.Services.Notifications.Command\MessageDelivery\SmsDeliveryStrategy.cs:line
>   19
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>
>   at
>   DAS.Services.Notifications.Command.Handlers.SendSmsNotificationHandler.<Handle>d__3.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\source\DigitalAirStrike\DAS_Platform\das.services.notifications\src\DAS.Services.Notifications.Command\Handlers\SendSmsNotificationHandler.cs:line
>   32
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at NServiceBus.LoadHandlersConnector.<Invoke>d__1.MoveNext() in
>   C:\Build\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\Incoming\LoadHandlersConnector.cs:line
>   40
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at NServiceBus.MutateIncomingMessageBehavior.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Build\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\MutateInstanceMessage\MutateIncomingMessageBehavior.cs:line
>   28
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   NServiceBus.DeserializeLogicalMessagesConnector.<Invoke>d__1.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Build\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\Incoming\DeserializeLogicalMessagesConnector.cs:line
>   31
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at NServiceBus.SubscriptionReceiverBehavior.<Invoke>d__1.MoveNext() in
>   C:\Build\src\NServiceBus.Core\Routing\MessageDrivenSubscriptions\SubscriptionReceiverBehavior.cs:line
>   29
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   NServiceBus.MutateIncomingTransportMessageBehavior.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Build\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\MutateTransportMessage\MutateIncomingTransportMessageBehavior.cs:line
>   27
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at NServiceBus.UnitOfWorkBehavior.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() in
>   C:\Build\src\NServiceBus.Core\UnitOfWork\UnitOfWorkBehavior.cs:line 26
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   NServiceBus.UnitOfWorkBehavior.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() in
>   C:\Build\src\NServiceBus.Core\UnitOfWork\UnitOfWorkBehavior.cs:line 49
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at NServiceBus.ProcessingStatisticsBehavior.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() in
>   C:\Build\src\NServiceBus.Core\Performance\Statistics\ProcessingStatisticsBehavior.cs:line
>   25
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   NServiceBus.ReceivePerformanceDiagnosticsBehavior.<Invoke>d__2.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Build\src\NServiceBus.Core\Performance\Statistics\ReceivePerformanceDiagnosticsBehavior.cs:line
>   40
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   NServiceBus.TransportReceiveToPhysicalMessageProcessingConnector.<Invoke>d__1.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Build\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\Incoming\TransportReceiveToPhysicalMessageProcessingConnector.cs:line
>   37
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at NServiceBus.MainPipelineExecutor.<Invoke>d__1.MoveNext() in
>   C:\Build\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\MainPipelineExecutor.cs:line 32
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   NServiceBus.Transport.SQLServer.ReceiveStrategy.<TryProcessingMessage>d__12.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Build\src\NServiceBus.SqlServer\Receiving\ReceiveStrategy.cs:line
>   33
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   NServiceBus.Transport.SQLServer.ReceiveWithTransactionScope.d__4.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Build\src\NServiceBus.SqlServer\Receiving\ReceiveWithTransactionScope.cs:line
>   99
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   NServiceBus.Transport.SQLServer.ReceiveWithTransactionScope.d__1.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Build\src\NServiceBus.SqlServer\Receiving\ReceiveWithTransactionScope.cs:line
>   39

The error suggests one of the follwing:

- The firewall is blocking DTC
- The computers can't resolve each other via NetBIOS
- Support for network transactions isn't enabled on one or both computers

I've added both inbound and outbound exceptions on the box where the application is running and the SQL Server box on port 135.

The SQL Server instance is running on a VM in Azure. I've added the exceptions to the network security group as well.

I've enabled network connections for DTC on both boxes.

The application box is running on DomainA while the VM is on DomainB

I'm having a bear of a time getting around this. What do I need to change to get this to work? Is there a workaround to prevent escalating to DTC?

UPDATE:
Both domains are run through some sort of Azure federation, so they were able to ping each other, they just could resolve each others' host names so I added the IP addresses to each box's host file and now they can find each other and everything seems to be working.

So I guess now, I'm wondering if there is a way to fix this through some sort of configuration so that I don't have to add host entries to every app box and every developer's box that wants to run locally to test.

Comment: This must be the longest and scariest exception stack trace I've seen here in SO (sorry for the off-topic comment)

Comment: HA yeah... a ton of layers in play there, it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try and avoid the use of MSDTC in your scenario, instead use the [Outbox feature](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/outbox/).

Does that help?

Comment: I looked at outbox very briefly as it did look like an alternative, and I tossed a quick config at it and it didn't seem to work. I didn't give it much effort; maybe I'll take a look at it again. Any resources for it would be helpful. The particular docs don't seem to put any context to the example so I didn't find it very helpful.

Comment: Will [these samples](https://docs.particular.net/samples/outbox/) help?